# What does wt in count() mean (R language)?

Tags: r, dplyr, count

I have googled back and forth, but I can't seem to find a good explanation, to non native English speaker, of what does it mean? Please give me a concrete example with and without wt.
Thank you

Comment: Is this a `dplyr` function/question? If so, please say it in the question and tagged it `dplyr`.

Comment: If you are talking about a variable, then in biology wt commonly refers to 'wild type' in contrast to a specific mutant. But of course without more information it's impossible to guess what you question is relating to.

Answer (score 8):

`wt` stands for `"weights"`.
The first example in `help('count')` **that uses object `df`**, is, in my opinion, very clear.

First, create the object.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~name,    ~gender,   ~runs,
  "Max",    "male",       10,
  "Sandra", "female",      1,
  "Susan",  "female",      4
)
```

**1.** Now, an example without `wt`.
As you can see from the data set above, there are

1. 2 rows with `gender == "female"`;
2. 1 row with `gender == "male"`.

And a non-weighted count will return those counts.

```
# counts rows:
df %>% count(gender)
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  gender     n
#  <chr>  <int>
#1 female     2
#2 male       1
```

**2.** Now an example with weights, argument `wt`.

Suppose that in the original data there were 10 rows with males and 5 rows with females. All male rows were obtained from the same individual, `"Max"`. And the female gender rows from two individuals, one row only for `"Sandra"` and 4 rows for `"Susan"`.

Then the user aggregated the original, unprocessed data by `name` and the result was the data as posted. To get counts that account for the *original*, use a weighted count.
This is what the comment above the `wt` example says.

```
# use the `wt` argument to perform a weighted count. This is useful
# when the data has already been aggregated once
# counts runs:
df %>% count(gender, wt = runs)
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  gender     n
#  <chr>  <dbl>
#1 female     5
#2 male      10
```

Answer (score 4):

Think of it as "group by sum", see example:

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl, wt = mpg)
#   cyl     n
# 1   4 293.3
# 2   6 138.2
# 3   8 211.4

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(mpg))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#     cyl     n
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4  293.
# 2     6  138.
# 3     8  211.
```

> **count {dplyr}**
> wt to perform weighted counts, switching the summary from `n = n()` to `n = sum(wt)`

Answer (score -1):

I will try to explain this in the simplest way possible.
If we have a dataset like this:
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb8md.png)

This shows different states, their counties, and the population for each county.

For example, we can see that 'California' has more than one county, each with their population.
Now, what if we want the total population for each state? That would mean adding the counties' population for a particular state together, right?
Now, this is where 'wt' argument comes in to action.
Take a look at this image
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WlnQ.png)

We can see now that we have counted the number of people in each state and weighted (wt) the *n* column by their population.

I hope this helps you to understand it better.
The snapshots of the images used are from my workspace on datacamp.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34240516)