# Need to count total amount of occurrences of each Diameter taking failure count per row into consideration

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO359.png)

I know how to use count function to count occurrences of each diameter, but not how to take the failure count into consideration

Comment: Do you want a weighted count? Also, images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Is this question a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65579489/what-does-wt-in-count-mean-r-language)?

Comment: Yes i basically want to duplicate the Diameter with the amount in the row of the count clumn

Comment: Try `df %>% count(Diameter_mm, wt = Failure.Count)`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.